# Android pem cert inside keystore

Tags: android, certificate, apk, digital-signature, pem

I have project not made by me but right now I need to fix some things,
Someone added an pem certificate (private key and certificate) inside a project which allows app to  communicate with server (used inside network_security_config trust anchor), the problem is that I need to build signed release apk, build process is crashing because pem cert is inside a project which is obvious rule violation, how can I add this pem cert inside a keystore(or create new one) or is there any other solution for this problem? Maybe the way of communication is bad.
Thank you for any answers!

I tried to create new keystore with cert inside but no success

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe in detail the crash of the build process, because usually the build process does not crash no matter where the keystore is located. Just the path to thekeyshore have to be correct and if course the password. It is also not clear what you want to achieve, just sign the APK with this key, a new key or any other key?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

To include the private key and certificate from the PEM file into a keystore, you can use the keytool command-line tool that comes with the Java Development Kit (JDK). Here are the general steps:

Convert PEM to PKCS12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey private-key.pem -in certificate.pem
```

This command will prompt you for a password for the keystore. Make sure to remember it, as you'll need it later.

Convert PKCS12 to JKS (Java Keystore):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

You'll need to provide the keystore password and set a new password for the JKS keystore.

Add Keystore to your App:

Move the generated keystore.jks file to a secure location in your project.
Update your build configuration to use this keystore for signing the release APK.
For example, in your build.gradle file, you might have something like this:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('path/to/your/keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'your_keystore_password'
            keyAlias 'your_key_alias'
            keyPassword 'your_key_password'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Replace 'path/to/your/keystore.jks', 'your_keystore_password', 'your_key_alias', and 'your_key_password' with your actual values.

After making these changes, you should be able to build a signed release APK without violating any security rules.

Note: Always handle keystore files, passwords, and keys securely. Ensure they are not shared or stored in public repositories.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy